# Jquery: How to recursively assign buttons on document ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I have multiple buttons and tables, I want to recursively assign each button id to respective table id.

For each button, the function should help me toggle their respective tables. Clicking button 1 ("#showHide01") will toggle table 1 ("#table01").

```js
// Working function
/*
$(function() {
    $("#showHide01").on("click", function() {
        $("#table01 tbody").toggle();
    });
});
*/

var buttonList = ["#showHide01","#showHide02a","#showHide02b","#showHide03a","#showHide03b","#showHide04"];
var tableList = ["#table01 tbody","#table02a tbody","#table02b tbody","#table03a tbody","#table03b tbody","#table04 tbody"]

$(function() {
 var i = 0, len = buttonList.length;
    for (i; i < len; i+=1) {
     $(buttonList[i]).on("click", function() {
         $(tableList[i]).toggle();
        });
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-info" id="showHide01">Show/hide table</button>
<table id="table01">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>D2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>001</td>
            <td>002</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button class="btn btn-info" id="showHide02a">Show/hide table</button>
<table id="table02a">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>D2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>001</td>
            <td>002</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button class="btn btn-info" id="showHide02b">Show/hide table</button>
<table id="table02b">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>D2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>001</td>
            <td>002</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button class="btn btn-info" id="showHide03a">Show/hide table</button>
<table id="table03a">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>D2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>001</td>
            <td>002</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button class="btn btn-info" id="showHide03b">Show/hide table</button>
<table id="table03b">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>D2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>001</td>
            <td>002</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button class="btn btn-info" id="showHide04">Show/hide table</button>
<table id="table04">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>D2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>001</td>
            <td>002</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is **assign** a single class to all your `<buttons>` and use a `data` attribute to separate which button toggles which table. That way you can create a single bind to all your buttons and get the id of the table you want to toggle **systematically**.

Basically the **html** it will go:

```
<button class="btn btn-info js_toggle-table" data-table-id="table01">Show/hide table</button>
<table id="table01">
```

And the **javascript/jquery** will be:

```
$(".js_toggle-table").on("click", function(el) {
  var tableIdSelector = "#" + $(el.target).data('table-id');
  $(tableIdSelector).toggle(); 
});
```

Check the updated snippet:

```js
$(".js_toggle-table").on("click", function(el) {
  var tableIdSelector = "#" + $(el.target).data('table-id');
  $(tableIdSelector).toggle(); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-info js_toggle-table" data-table-id="table01">Show/hide table 01</button>
<table id="table01">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Table 1</th>
            <th>D2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>001</td>
            <td>002</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button class="btn btn-info js_toggle-table" data-table-id="table02a">Show/hide table 02a</button>
<table id="table02a">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Table 02a</th>
            <th>D2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>001</td>
            <td>002</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button class="btn btn-info js_toggle-table" data-table-id="table02b">Show/hide table 02b</button>
<table id="table02b">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Table 2 b</th>
            <th>D2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>001</td>
            <td>002</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button class="btn btn-info js_toggle-table" data-table-id="table03a">Show/hide table 3 a</button>
<table id="table03a">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Table 3 a</th>
            <th>D2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>001</td>
            <td>002</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button class="btn btn-info js_toggle-table" data-table-id="table03b">Show/hide table 3 b</button>
<table id="table03b">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Table 3 b</th>
            <th>D2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>001</td>
            <td>002</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button class="btn btn-info js_toggle-table" data-table-id="table04">Show/hide table 4</button>
<table id="table04">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Table 4</th>
            <th>D2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>001</td>
            <td>002</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Cheers!

**EDIT:** I changed the names of the **buttons** and **table** to make it clear which one was disappearing when the button was clicked.

Comment: I noticed that when you start running the code, the button clicked will hide the next table instead of the current table. ie, I click 1st button, 2nd table will be toggled instead of 1st table

Comment: Not really, it's because when the table is hidden the second button appears next to the first one. I've **updated** my answer with a snippet that contains the name of the `table` that will be toggled on the `button` label and also the id of the table on the first `th` of it.

Comment: @Shawn does the updated answer solve your problem? If so, please mark it as the correct answer for future reference ;).

Comment: Thanks, it works, I am just debugging your code, not very good with jquery yet :)

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to each button (like "toggle-button"):

```
<button class="btn btn-info toggle-button" id="showHide04">Show/hide table</button>
```

Then you can take this script:

```
$(".toggle-button").click(function() {
  $(this).next().find("tbody").toggle(); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution is so simple!

Answer (score 1):

To make the code work you have to keep a copy of **i** at its current value with a closure. This page gives a bit of a walkthrough of the issue you came across. http://www.mennovanslooten.nl/blog/post/62

```js
var buttonList = ["#showHide01", "#showHide02a", "#showHide02b", "#showHide03a", "#showHide03b", "#showHide04"];
var tableList = ["#table01 tbody", "#table02a tbody", "#table02b tbody", "#table03a tbody", "#table03b tbody", "#table04 tbody"]

$(function() {
  var i = 0,
    len = buttonList.length;
  for (i; i < len; i += 1) {
    $(buttonList[i]).on("click", (function(i) { /* IIFE closure */
      /* e is the event */
      return function(e) { /* i is now available at the value it was at point of execution in loop */
        $(tableList[i]).toggle();
      }
    })(i) /* immediately executed passing in loop 'i' */ );
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-info" id="showHide01">Show/hide table</button>
<table id="table01">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>D2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>001</td>
      <td>002</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button class="btn btn-info" id="showHide02a">Show/hide table</button>
<table id="table02a">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>D2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>001</td>
      <td>002</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button class="btn btn-info" id="showHide02b">Show/hide table</button>
<table id="table02b">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>D2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>001</td>
      <td>002</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button class="btn btn-info" id="showHide03a">Show/hide table</button>
<table id="table03a">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>D2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>001</td>
      <td>002</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button class="btn btn-info" id="showHide03b">Show/hide table</button>
<table id="table03b">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>D2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>001</td>
      <td>002</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button class="btn btn-info" id="showHide04">Show/hide table</button>
<table id="table04">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>D2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>001</td>
      <td>002</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This issue doesn't involve recursion though.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the solution and the article, not aware of closures. Will read up on this part. Thanks!